# Combining information in one table and moving it to another in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to create usernames for a faux database for a class by taking the names of the 'volunteers' and crafting the username for it.

I have the first and last names in one table and am creating the username in a separate table.

I had no issues moving a ID Number from one table to the other, but I am having issues taking the names from the table, combining them, and copying it over to the other one.

My code I used (without success) is as follows:

`INSERT INTO Username (IDNumber, username)` -- these are the two variables in the new table

`SELECT ID_Number FROM Person` -- this works without an issue, ID_Number is the variable name in the Person table, which I'm taking it from. I'm including this so I have a reference if I need to join the tables at some point

`SELECT CONCAT(FirstName, LastName) FROM Person`; -- this is what I'm actually having issues with. If I could get in contact with my teacher quicker, I'd ask if I could have two more columns for the names in the new table and combine them that way, because I have a feeling it'd be easier.

What am I doing wrong here?

Basically, I want to take the first and last name from the first table and combine them for insertion into the new table.

Edit: Rereading what I typed, I decided to make myself a little clearer: I tried the IDNumber by itself and it worked without an issue. When I try those three lines together, it returns an error telling me to check the syntax.

Comment: There aren't any *faux* databases except flat text files. You're creating a real database. You just aren't planning to put it into production for the next twenty years. (Plus many databases like this end up in production by accident.)  Don't sell yourself short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you want `CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName)` otherwise you'll get `LarryEllison` rather than `Larry Ellison` in your new table.

You're on the right track [with `INSERT ... SELECT`.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) You probably want

```
  INSERT INTO UserName (IDNumber, username)
       SELECT IDNumber, 
              CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) username
         FROM Person
```

The idea is to write a `SELECT` statement that matches your `INSERT` statement column for column. You can test all this nondestructively by running the `SELECT` without the `INSERT` and convincing yourself it looks right.

Comment: If it's for a username, chances are pretty good he doesn't want the space in there.

Comment: @GregSchmidt  That's possible. But now he knows what might happen.

Comment: Actually, I did not want the space there. I knew that the space wouldn't be there, otherwise I would include the space in quotes like that (at least, that's what the one course I took in C++ taught me). Also, that worked, thanks. I kind of figured I was typing it in wrong since that's what it told me lol